# Sybase: how to show the values of the current session variables?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I can do for example:

```
> set chained on
```

But how can I see the current value of `chained`, or all current session variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [list of ASE global variables](https://help.sap.com/viewer/2df920cd5b1644e5a065d55b637d5e92/16.0.3.7/en-US/aaed9e75bc2b1014bcb5dc46d648f881.html).

For the current chained status: `select @@tranchained`:

- returns 0 if chained mode is disabled (`set chained off`)
- returns 1 if chained mode is enabled  (`set chained on` )

Comment: Okay, but @@tranchained is not global. If I open 2 connections, I only see in the connection where I did > set chained on, that @@tranchained=1. Maybe I do not understand what a global variable is? The documentation says: Some global variables are session-specific, while others are server instance-specific. So instance-specific are the 'real' global variables?

Comment: Yeah, Sybase could've picked a better name, or name**s** to better distinguish between instance-level and session-level variables; you're more than welcome to take the issue up with SAP :-)      generally speaking the 'global variables' are set by the system (ie, the user cannot explicitly set the value of a 'global' variable, eg, `select @@tranchained=5` is not doable) ... so perhaps they could've named them 'system variables' ... ?